# CMD to PowerShell converter

Tags: powershell, networking, cmd, scripting

Does anyone know how to convert this CMD script to PowerShell script?

reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge\ExtensionInstallBlocklist" /v 1 /t REG_SZ /d *

I have tried saving it as ps1 file, the weird thing is that it works when I run it in PowerShell terminal but when I save it as a powershell file and try to run it I get an error.

EDIT:
PowerShell script files were disabled due to security reasons but I've enabled it now, I am using Windows 11 and would need to run that file as an admin but can't find a way to do it.

Thanks

Comment: `reg add` should work, given you launched the PowerShell script with administrator permissions (elevated). The PowerShell way would be `Set-ItemProperty`, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-itemproperty?view=powershell-7.3#example-2-create-a-registry-entry-and-value

Comment: Use `Start-Process -Verb RunAs powershell` to start an elevated PowerShell session.

Comment: Just to emphasize what others have said: what you have here is _not_ a CMD script. It is merely a command line invocation of the `REG.EXE` tool. You can invoke it in that way (almost) unchanged in several shells. Including `CMD.EXE`, Powershell, even bash (on Windows).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the equivalent command in pure Powershell. This will need to be run from an elevated Powershell prompt

```
New-Item "HKLM:SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge\ExtensionInstallBlocklist" | New-ItemProperty -Name 1 -Value * -PropertyType String
```